# Web2py re-authentication when saving auth_user changes

Tags: authentication, web2py

I am currently using a form created by auth.profile(), where users can change their profile information. I would like users to re-authenticate themselves before they can save changes; they must reenter their password before changes from the form are saved.

I haven't been able to find anything on re-authentication with Web2py, any ideas on how I would accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a "password" field to the form, then checked the password in the onvalidation function.

I got the idea to compare the plain text pw to the encrypted pw in the database from the web2py groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/web2py/eqbXmseZ6XA/abnGIMevI6wJ